# Is it true for all natural number $x$ that $x \le\prod\limits_{p_i\le x} (1+\frac {\ln x} {\ln p_i})$?

Tags: prime-numbers

I just wonder is this inequality  true for all natural number $x$ that $$x \le\prod_{p_i\le x} \left(1+\frac {\ln x} {\ln p_i}
\right)?$$

From prime factorization, we have $$x=p_{j_{1}}^{c_{j_{1}}}p_{j_{2}}^{c_{j_{2}}}\cdots p_{j_{r}}^{c_{j_{r}}}$$ for primes $p_{j_{k}}^{c_{j_{k}}}\le x$ and $c_{j_{k}}\in{\mathbb N}$ for $k=1,2,...,r$.

Then how can I proceed ?

Comment: It should be true. RHS is basically $2^{\pi(x)} \approx 2^{x/\log x}$ which is sooooooooooo much bigger than $x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Count all the products
$$p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\cdots p_k^{\alpha_k}$$
where $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_k$ are the prime numbers up to $x$, and
$$0\le \alpha_i\le\frac{\ln x}{\ln p_i}$$
for each $i$.  By unique factorisation, the number of products is equal to the number of choices for the exponents, and this is exactly
$$\prod_{i=1}^k \left(1+\left\lfloor\frac {\ln x} {\ln p_i}\right\rfloor\right)\ .$$
However, any positive integer up to $x$ can be written
$$x=p_1^{\beta_1}p_2^{\beta_2}\cdots p_k^{\beta_k}$$
for some $\beta_1,\beta_2,\ldots,\beta_k$, and we have
$$p_j^{\beta_j}\le x\quad\Rightarrow\quad \beta_j\le\frac{\ln x}{\ln p_j}\ .$$
Therefore the numbers we have counted include all positive integers up to $x$ (and usually, many more besides), and hence
$$x\le\prod_{i=1}^k \left(1+\left\lfloor\frac {\ln x} {\ln p_i}\right\rfloor\right)\le\prod_{p_i\le x} \left(1+\frac {\ln x} {\ln p_i}\right)\ .$$